# No page number on \appendixpage

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, appendices

I am using the `appendix` package with the `\appendixpage` command to insert a "Appendices" title page. However, I was wondering how I could avoid that there is a pagenumber on this inserted page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
```

\tableofcontents

\appendix
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Some title}
Some text

\end{document}

Mind that the `\noappendicestocpagenum` is about a page number in the ToC, not in the text, so this is unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The page style of that appendix page is *plain*. You could temporarily redefine it to be empty:

```
\appendix
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\appendixpage
\makeatother
\endgroup
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
```

The important line is just

```
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
```

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` have been used to be able to work with `@` in macro names, `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` limit the scope of this redefinition. So afterwards, *plain* is normal *plain* again.

Referring to lockstep's comment, you can do this in the preamble instead. Define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myappendixpage}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \appendixpage
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

and later in the document just use it:

```
\appendix
\myappendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
```

Or redefine `\appendixpage` in the preamble:

```
\let\plainappendixpage\appendixpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\appendixpage}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \plainappendixpage
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Note, if you use `\let` in situations with a macro with optional argument or one made by `\DeclareRobustCommand`, use `\LetLtxMacro` of the `letltxmacro` package instead. Here, `\let` is sufficient.

Comment: I prefer "preamble-only"  solutions. ;-)

Comment: Like often, it's directly demonstrated in the body. Of course it can go to the preamble, for example just define `\myappendixpage` with this code in the preamble and use that instead.

Comment: @Lockstep: I agree. But on the other hand, Stefan's solution is less dependent on the internals of the appendix package, right?

Comment: @Stefan: I was about to ask that. Would it also be possible to redefine `\appendixpage`?

Comment: @Matthias: a) Stefan's solution at least needs to check what the `appendix` package actually does (e.g., it could have defined an entirely new page style and used it) b) You're using the package, and therefore should not shy away from a solution that also "uses" its internals.

Comment: @Lockstep: I disagree with b), this breaks the encapsulation/information hiding principle, which is a cornerstone of functional and object oriented programming. Anyway, if there is no other way, it is of course not a big problem to use internals.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, I added a version.

Comment: @Matthias: Re b) -- You may be right in general, but in the specific case the `appendix` package simply hardcodes a specific page style for the "Appendices" title page, which surely is also bad programming practice.

Comment: @lockstep: Agreed :)

Comment: @lockstep I like patching :) However, I hesitate recommending it, though it's often very short code.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm using this in my book to create a plain appendix page and I like it.  The only problem I'm having is that it seems to show up in my TOC looking like a chapter (with no number, which is good), but in the PDF TOC, it is a chapter.  Is there any way to make it a part (but still plain)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the `\@chap@pppage` macro.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\appendix
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Some title}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This time you beat me by 40 seconds!