# no page number on appendix divider page

Tags: appendices

I have found some links on here (for example [No page number on \appendixpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37357/no-page-number-on-appendixpage)) that explain how to remove the pagenumber from the divider appendix page, but how can I use this when using the appendices environment? Than the proposed solutions are no longer working and I would really like to use the environment since I would like to have 'Appendix' added in the toc as well.

So I would like to get the same behavior as in the other question (no page number on divider appendices page) but then inside the appendices environment.

MWE:

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
 \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{First chapter}
 \chapter{Second chapter}

 \begin{appendices}
 \chapter{First appendix chapter name}
 \chapter{Second appendix chapter name}
 \end{appendices}

 \end{document}
```

So in this MWE I would like to not show the number 4 on the Appendices divider page. The toc is ok as it is.

Comment: Can you please give us a MWE?

Comment: What's wrong with e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37360/36296, it also adds "Appendix" to the ToC?

Comment: @samcarter when I apply that answer it does not add 'Appendix' to each chapter title in the toc as is done in the MWE I have added

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the ToC entry. I thought it should just be an entry in front of the appendices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
 \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

 \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
    \clear@ppage
    \thispagestyle{empty}%%%% This line was "plain" in the original definition
    \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
    \null\vfil
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \Huge \bfseries \appendixpagename\par}%
    \if@dotoc@pp
    \addappheadtotoc
    \fi
    \vfil\newpage
    \if@twoside
    \if@openright
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage
    \fi
    \fi
    \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
    \fi
}
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{First chapter}
    \chapter{Second chapter}

    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{First appendix chapter name}
        \chapter{Second appendix chapter name}
    \end{appendices}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks works like a charm! I wish I was able to actually work with this kind of stuff but right now I'm just a novice able to apply pre-defined package behavior, not enough when you are a perfectionist

Comment: You could use `xpatch` to change the page style instead of redefining the whole command.  Can I edit an `xpatch` version into your answer?

Comment: @Thruston Interessting idea, maybe post it as an additional answer?

Comment: @Ingrid Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way of patching the command without using `renewcommand`.   You can learn more about patching from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/please-tutor-the-usage-of-patchcmd-and-xpatch).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix chapter name}
\chapter{Second appendix chapter name}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

A better long term solution would be for the authors of `appendix` to provide an option to switch on and off this behaviour.

Comment: indeed a much shorter solution and works as expected as well

I could not agree with you more that it should be an option that can be switched on/off and as for I am concerned the standard should be switched off, it just looks strange to have a page number there but I guess that is just a personal opinion

Comment: @ingrid - perhaps you should email them with the suggestion...