# Remove page number from Appendix section header

Tags: appendices

I am generating an appendix in my report using the command

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}
\include{appendix1}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

This command itself is generating a section header page as shown in image. This page contains a page number. I don't want a page number on this section header page and rest pages should have page number as it ease. How to do this
[image]

Comment: Welcome again to TeX.SX! Please have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Which package defines the `appendices` environment?

Comment: You example produces error messages but not the result you've shown. Please post a [minimal *but working* example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). This would help us to reproduce your problem and to test our suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{%
\thispagestyle{plain}}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the `\appendixpage` command in the preamble of your document like so.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}

\let\plainappendixpage\appendixpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\appendixpage}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \plainappendixpage
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{appendices}
        \appendixpage 
        \lipsum
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

It should be noted that this code comes from "Stefan Kottwitz" on [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37357/no-page-number-on-appendixpage) so he should be credited and the question could be marked as duplicate.

Comment: No it is not working.

Comment: Then please post a MWE in your question so that I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried doing as mention in first reply of this link--  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37357/no-page-number-on-appendixpage   but problem with this is it is generating new section header page without number but previous page remains as it ease.

Comment: please tell what is MWE

Comment: Minimal Working Example -- The code you provide us at the moment can't be compiled. Because we do not have the appendix1 file and it lacks `\usepackage{appendix}`.